# @State not updating SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, state

I'm pretty new to Swift and SwiftUI, so this might have some clear answers that I'm overlooking. My goal is to have this progress ring update every time a button is clicked. I want the button to update `DailyGoalProgress` by a certain number, and that works. However, I also want `DailyGoalProgress` to then be divided by a number to make this `@State`. As I said, the DailyGoalProgress updates but the `@State` does not and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here is an abbreviated version of my code:

```
struct SummaryView: View {
    
    @AppStorage ("DailyGoalProgress") var DailyGoalProgress: Int = 0
    @State var progressValue: Float = 0 //This just stays at zero and never changes even with the button press
    var body: some View {
       ProgressBar(progress: self.$progressValue, DailyGoalProgress: self.$DailyGoalProgress)     
    }
}
```

Here is another view:

```
@Binding var DailyGoalProgress: Int
@Binding var progressValue: Float
var body: some View {

    Button(action: {DailyGoalProgress += tokencount; progressValue = Float(DailyGoalProgress / 30)}) {
                            Text("Mark This Task As Completed")
                                .font(.title3)
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        }
                    }.frame(width: 330.0, height: 65.0).padding(.bottom, 75.0)
                    Spacer()
                }.padding(.top, 125.0)
            }
            
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need two different variables to track progress? You could just utilise  @AppStorage alone.

Comment: @TusharSharma I also display `DailyGoalProgress` on its own, so yes I need both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is about **Int to Float**, **DailyGoalProgress** is **Int** and you should convert it to **Float** first then divid it to 30.0, then it will work.

**It called Inference! Swift wants help you in its own way, but it makes problem to you.**

*if you want detail what happens: when you divid DailyGoalProgress to 30 what ever the result is it will taken as Int, then what does mean? that mean number between 0 to 1 became always 0, then you gave 0 to Float and also nothing happens!*

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @AppStorage ("DailyGoalProgress") var DailyGoalProgress: Int = 0
    @State var progressValue: Float = 0

    var body: some View {
        
        Spacer()
        
        Text(DailyGoalProgress.description)
        
        Text(progressValue.description)

        ProgressBar(DailyGoalProgress: $DailyGoalProgress, progressValue: $progressValue)

        Spacer()
        
    }
}


struct ProgressBar: View {
    
    @Binding var DailyGoalProgress: Int
    @Binding var progressValue: Float
    
    let tokencount: Int = 30  // <<: Here for example I used 30

    var body: some View {

        Button(action: {
            
            DailyGoalProgress += tokencount
            progressValue = Float(DailyGoalProgress)/30.0 // <<: Here
            
        }, label: {
            
            Text("Mark This Task As Completed")
                .font(.title3)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)

        })
        
 
    }
    
}
```